# Is there a way to reuse enums in other classes?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to reuse enums in other classes?

For example,
I have a class using another class's enums. However, I want to avoid having to type the other class's namespace every time I use that class's enums for my active class.

Comment: why not name the other classes namespace the same as yours and then you won't have to do that..

Comment: You need to provide more specific details.  Currently the answer is: "it depends".

Comment: 1. Put the enums in a common namespace and use a `using` statement at the top of each class. 2. Put both classes in the same namespace.

Comment: `using MyEnum = MyNamespace.AnotherClass.MyEnum;`

Comment: Make the enum public on namespace A, then include namespace A on your second class via a using directive.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035073/whats-this-c-sharp-using-directive

Answer (score 0):

Is there a good reason why you can't just use a `using` statement?

```
using Namespace.With.Enum;

namespace Namespace.Without.Enum 
{
    public class Foobar 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This should allow you to use the enum inside `Foobar` without needing to preface it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the issue with putting a using statement at the top of each file.

```
 namespace MyNameSpace.EnumNamespace
 {
    public enum MyEnum
    {
         One,Two,Three
    }
 }
```

And in a separate file

```
using MyNamespace.EnumNamespace;


namespace AnotherNamespace
{
        public class AnotherClass
        {
            //somewhere in the same file
            public void SomeMethod(MyEnum enumValue)
            {
                //Do stuff
            }
        }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also assign an alias as well.

```
using MyEnumAlias = MyNameSpace.EnumNamespace.MyEnum
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want put namespace and class name, e.g.

```
  namespace AnotherNamespace {
    ...
    public class AnotherClass {
      ...
      public enum MyEnum {
        One, 
        Two,
        Three 
     }
    }
    ...
  }

  ...

  namespace MyNamespace { 
    ...
    AnotherNamespace.AnotherClass.MyEnum v = ...
```

you can try creating *synonym* via `using`:

```
  namespace MyNamespace {
    using MyEnum = AnotherNamespace.AnotherClass.MyEnum;

    ...

    MyEnum v = ...
```